# How to find full SQL server address (not just localhost)

Tags: php, sql-server, cpanel

I purchased my first domain through GoDaddy and cPanel hosting to accompany it. I'd like to find the full address of my SQL database to connect with it from PHP files that aren't on the server. For files on the server that interface with the database, I just use "localhost" but that doesn't work if the files aren't stored on the server. How can I connect to the SQL database and/or how can I find the full address of my server? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Isn't this a question you should be asking GoDaddy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**VIEWING YOUR DATABASE DETAILS WITH SHARED HOSTING ACCOUNTS**

After creating your database, you can find its details, including its hostname, in your control panel.

- Log in to your Account Manager.
- Click Web Hosting.
- Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Manage.
- In the Databases area, click MySQL or MSSQL depending on the database
  type for which you want the host name.
- From your list of databases, click Actions next to the database you
  want to use, and then click Details.

Your database's details displays including its username, host name, and a link to reset its password.

Comment: Thanks for the help @jlocker but I only see "Rename" and "Delete" under "Actions" — am I looking in the right place? From the Databases area I chose "MySQL Databases" and found a list of my databases, but I couldn't find "Details" mentioned near any of them.

Comment: @Andrew In the Manage Database, click the dropdown menu and choose Details